# The FAQ is confused about my powers

Tags: support, suggested-edits

For users with reputation between 2000 (inclusive) and something, the FAQ says that we have the following abilities:

```
2000    Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits
```

The first part is accurate, as you've no doubt seen. The second part, however ... occasionally I find myself poking around in the FAQ for something. I see the list of privileges, panic when I see that I'm supposed to be helping to approve or reject edits and I remember that I haven't ever done any ... and yet that page is unavailable to me.

That's fine, by the way - I'm more than happy to wait until I have the appropriate reputation to use that power - I'd just prefer that the FAQ shows the correct reputation, whatever it may be, to approve or reject edits.

Comment: thanks for the correction, Matthew ... glad to know it is not a bug!

Comment: Also, all privileges stack, so the only way to lose the 'edit everything' privilege is to have less than 2k reputation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can approve and reject suggested edits, you just won't see the queue of them at the top of the page or have access to the all suggested edits page until you hit 10k rep. If a post has a suggested edit you'll see a "edit (0)" button, instead of "edit".

Clicking on edit will bring up the suggestion, from where you can approve or reject the edit.

Comment: Was going to answer this.  I was confused by the same thing before I hit 10k.

Comment: Same here, except I haven't hit 10k yet. Seems a bit silly that I'm theoretically trusted with reviewing suggested edits, but probably won't ever see one.