# Where can I review suggested edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The FAQ is confused about my powers](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/the-faq-is-confused-about-my-powers)

According to the FAQ I should have the ability to "vote to approve or reject suggested edits", however I can't find where on the site I can do this. Where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this a little while ago and found it confusing, but it is by design.

See the following Meta SO question: [Users with 5k+ rep have "approve tag wiki edits" privilege but can't see list of suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80709/users-with-5k-rep-have-approve-tag-wiki-edits-privilege-but-cant-see-list-of)

You only need 2000 rep to approve suggested edits, but you need 10000 rep to see the list of suggested edits.

Basically, at our low rep values, you can't see the big list.  However, if you are ever on a question / answer and the links at the bottom say:

> link edit(0) flag

That indicates that the question / answer has a pending suggestion.  Clicking on edit(0) will take you to the page where you can approve or reject the suggested edit.

**EDIT**

Screenshot to prove I don't have access to the list:

[image: No Suggested Edits!]

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure you can do it from your rep number. It should be the most right option in the review menu. Once you get 10,000 you unlock the tools menu, which lets you view flags and the like.

Comment: You can absolutely see the list before 10,000 rep.

Comment: They changed it.  [You now only need 5k rep to see the list.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105870/152101)  (@victoriah Note that Travel is still a beta so it uses a different privileges scale.)